# Why SegmentedControl move back when click it in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I set the transform of `SegmentedControl` in `viewdidAppear` function and change the position of `SegmentedControl`, when I click the `SegmentedControl` ,The position of SegmentedControl is change(move back)

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.videoSegmented.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.videoSegmented.transform, CGFloat(self.degreesToRadians(90)));
    var frame = self.videoSegmented.frame
    self.videoSegmented.frame = self.seguementView.frame
}

func degreesToRadians(x:Double) -> Double{
    return M_PI * x / 180
}
```

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: @rakeshbs yes,I use it

Comment: That's the problem then.  Autolayout takes complete control of your view layout.  If you want to do something like this you'll need to either turn autolayout off or change your constraints to achieve your desired results.  Since you're rotating a standard view, you'll probably need to disable autolayout or wrap the segmented control in another view with a fixed size, preset for the rotation.